# Can Spring inject a qualified class with dependencies having the same qualifier?

Tags: java, spring

Suppose I have a (unworkable) code like this:

```
public class ServiceB {
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("backup")
    private ServiceWithDependency ser;
}

public class ServiceWithDependency {
    @Autowired
    private DepA depA; 
}

@Configuration
public class BeanInjection {
    @Bean("backup")
    public DepA getBackUpA() {
        return new BackUp(); //implements DepA
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public DepA getA() {
        return new PrimaryA(); //implements DepA
    }
}
```

I would want Spring to autowire ServiceWithDependency in ServiceB with the dependency annotated by "backup".

Is there a way to achieve that? Besides the more direct way of creating another ServiceWithDependency class and annotate it and its dependency with @Qualifer("backup").

Comment: `getBackUpA` returns a `DepA`. `ServiceWithDependency ser` is a different type. Why (and how) would Spring be able to wire that?

Comment: @knittl I know it doesn't, but I want to know if there is some way to achieve that. Something like @ Profile, but I don't want to have different profiles.